# When trying to do a docker pull using exec.Command() in golang, I am not seeing the progress bars

Tags: docker, go

I am using the Go exec package to execute a `docker pull debian` command:

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("docker", "pull", "debian")
    stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    cmd.Start()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
    return nil
}
```

But it never shows me the progress bar. It only shows an update when it is fully complete. For larger images over a GB it is hard to see if there is progess being made. This is what it shows:

```
e9afc4f90ab0: Pulling fs layer
e9afc4f90ab0: Verifying Checksum
e9afc4f90ab0: Download complete
e9afc4f90ab0: Pull complete
```

Is it possible to get output similar to what I see when I run `docker pull debian` in the terminal or something that I can use to show progress?:

```
e9afc4f90ab0: Downloading [==========>                                        ]  10.73MB/50.39MB
```

Comment: The progress bar requires a tty, and `StdoutPipe` is not a tty.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for your help. Is there a way to show progress if `StdoutPipe` is not the correct solution?

Comment: You should probably prefer the [Docker Go SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/#go-sdk) to trying to invoke `docker` subcommands.  It will be up to your application to present progress, though.

Comment: @perseverance: if this in used on the cli, you could just assign the actual stdout rather than scanning and rewriting the output. If not, you probably should do this programmatically through the docker API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David mentionned, you would rather use the [official docker engine SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) to interact with docker.

Initialize the docker client

```
cli, _ := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv, client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation())
```

Pull the image

```
reader, _ := cli.ImagePull(context.Background(), "hello-world", types.ImagePullOptions{})
```

Parse the json stream

```
id, isTerm := term.GetFdInfo(os.Stdout)
_ = jsonmessage.DisplayJSONMessagesStream(reader, os.Stdout, id, isTerm, nil)
```

You will get the same output as the docker cli provide when you do a *docker pull hello-world*